# GalleryView 1.1 jquery plugin customization

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2010

I am using GalleryView 1.1 to build an Image slider webpart like [this](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2010/archive/2011/07/08/sharepoint-2010-cookbook-create-a-slide-image-webpart-using-jquery-in-sharepoint.aspx).

I am looking to stop the rotation of images on reaching first and last image in the filmstrip but it seems bit out of reach.

Can anyone please suggest ways of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

In the time it would take to figure it out, I could build a full working example using a different slider plugin.  I suggest you get a slider plugin which has documentation and is more modern.  Sorry this doesn't answer your question, but the GalleryView slider is over 2 years old... which is dead and rotting in web speak.

http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/

http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/ (costs money, but works great)

http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/09/jquery-image-slider-plugins.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ryan. I know it is more easier to use galleryview 3.0 but I have few customization for which it is more suitable for the requirements.

Comment: I cannot see how an older version of a plugin could suit your requirements better than a current version.  The old version is not documented and therefore I (and anyone else) will not read source code to try and figure out how to retro fit a decrepit plugin to suit your needs.  Sorry.